# How to remove apostrophes and parathenses in output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, output

```
a=str(input("Enter string: "))
b=str(input("Enter another: "))

def switch(x, y): 
    x, y = y, x
    return x, y

print (switch(a, b))
```

output is for example: ('there', 'hello')
I want to remove parathenses and ''

Comment: Don't print the list, print each element separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep the output of your function the same (a tuple), you can use use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to print the tuple separated by a space:

```
a = input("Enter string: ")
b = input("Enter another: ")

def switch(x, y):
    return y, x

print(' '.join(switch(a, b)))
```

**Small note**: I changed the method to just be `return y, x`, since the other two lines in the method did not seem needed in this case :)

Comment: makes sense now. But how does the ' '.join function remove the characters?

Comment: Ah - it actually doesn't remove any characters. It's just that when you just print a tuple itself, it will add the parenthesis and the quotes to provide a string representation of a tuple of strings. The same goes for a list...if you print a Python list intialized as `['hello', 'world']`, it will print as `['hello', 'world']` with the quotes and brackets to indicate it's a list (as opposed to just the strings within the list).

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `switch` is a tuple of 2 items (a pair), which is passed to the `print` function as a single argument. And `print` converts each of its arguments to a string with implicit `str`, and the `('', '')` come from the string representation of this tuple.

What you want is to pass each item in the pair separately.

As this is Python 3, you just need to add one character:

```
print(*switch(a, b))
```

The `*` means "pass the elements of the following iterable as separate positional arguments", so it is shorthand (in this case) for

```
value = switch(a, b)
print(value[0], value[1])
```

Print normally prints the values separated by a single space. If you want another separator, for example `,`, you can use the `sep` keyword argument:

```
print(*switch(a, b), sep=', ')
```

---

Finally, the `str()` in your example seem unnecessary.